# How to filter NSMutableArray objects that doesn't contain a string?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have NSMutableArray with NSString objects.
How can I filter it to get only the objects, which DOES NOT contain a string?
I tried NSPredicate to filter objects which contain a string:

```
NSString *match = @"My text"; 

    NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", match];

    [self.filesList setArray:[self.filesList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sPredicate]];
```

Is there anything similar, but to filter it vice-versa? Some kind of " !contains " ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing an NSPredicate that returns true if condition is not met](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166401/writing-an-nspredicate-that-returns-true-if-condition-is-not-met)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

`NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@)", match];`

Comment: Thanks! It works! Also, it can be done by creating a new array with objects, that contain a string and then using removeObjectsInArray