# Is there a function similar to the sql "NOT IN" in Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

SQL Command

> SELECT GAMELOCALTEAM FROM GAME WHERE GAMELOCALTEAM NOT IN ‘TBC’ ORDER
>   BY GAMELOCALTEAM

I would like to write sql command in objective c. My worte code below

```
NSManagedObjectContext * context = ((AFLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] ).managedObjectContext;
NSFetchRequest* fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@“game”];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@“game” inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT(gamelocalteam IN 'tbc')"];
[fetch setPredicate:predicate];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescreptor =[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"gamelocalteam" ascending:YES];
[fetch setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescreptor]];
NSAttributeDescription* attributeDescription = [entity.attributesByName objectForKey:@"gamelocalteam"];
[fetch setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:attributeDescription, nil]];
[fetch setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObject:attributeDescription]];
[fetch setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
NSError *error = nil;
_team = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
```

Predicate Format is `@"NOT(gamelocalteam IN 'tbc')` if this call app is crashing.

Is possible do `NOT IN`?

Comment: This link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476466/use-an-nspredicate-to-detect-not-contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
@"NOT gamelocalteam contains[cd] 'tbc'"
```

Code Below

```
NSManagedObjectContext * context = ((AFLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] ).managedObjectContext;
NSFetchRequest* fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@“game”];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@“game” inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:>@"NOT gamelocalteam contains[cd] 'tbc'"];
[fetch setPredicate:predicate];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescreptor =[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"gamelocalteam" ascending:YES];
[fetch setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescreptor]];
NSAttributeDescription* attributeDescription = [entity.attributesByName objectForKey:@"gamelocalteam"];
[fetch setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:attributeDescription, nil]];
[fetch setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObject:attributeDescription]];
[fetch setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
NSError *error = nil;
_team = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your predicate code will look like below,

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (%K CONTAINS[c] %@)",@"someKey", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some String"]];
```

Thanks!